# How to use plain SQL as derived table in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I think the title is quite self-explanatory. How can I use fetched plain sql as derived table in nested selects?

For example I want to fetch

```sql
select a.a, a.b from (select c.a, c.b from c) as a
```

and the

```sql
(select c.a, c.b from c)
```

part is a complicated postgres query which is not supported by JOOQ.

How can I make something like this:

```java
nested = create.fetch("select c.a, c.b from c")

create.select(...)
    .from(nested)
    .fetch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DSL.table(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-java.lang.String-)

```java
Table<?> nested = DSL.table("(select c.a, c.b from c)").as("a")

create.select(...)
      .from(nested)
      .fetch();
```